# what is the difference between an integration test and normal test with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am reading a couple rails books right now and can't really seem to understand when to use one kind of test over this other. Are there some simple rules to follow to know when to use an integration test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Testing philosophy is to test everything apart:

- model
- controller
- view

And using mocks to do the trick:

- mocking model to test your controllers
- mocking controllers to test your views

At the very end, you need integration tests, which are requests to your app to check that everything works perfectly together.

To sum up:

- basic test = unit test => separation
- integration test => all together

Comment: "Basic" tests are more commonly called unit tests, because you're testing one discrete unit of code at a time.

Comment: @Tobias, you're right, I edited he answer to use the proper vocabulary